# AWS API Gateway Authorizer using Cognito Identity Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

The test enviornment for the API Gateway..... Cognito Authorizer.

What value is it expecting ?
I tried to use **accessKeyId** returned from **CognitoIdentityCredentials** and it did not work.

[Identity Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7fyX.png)

'[Testing the accessKeyId gives Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XajKY.png)

I also tried **_identityId** and that did not work as well.

The error for both is "Unauthorized request"

Comment: is that screenshot taken from aws website?

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do and how are you testing

Comment: That is a screen shot from aws test screen

Comment: I am trying to allow API Gateway to be called only if user is identified

Comment: what do you get as a result of successful login to cognito, a JWT token or `accessKeyId`

Comment: its an object with a bunch of stuff that include accessKeyId as one of the elements

Comment: do you have a secret key ?

Comment: it does come with a secret key aswell....I tried using that and that did not work

Comment: ok can you test api access using postman. Also makesure the API gateway endpoint is set to use `AWS_IAM` authentication

Answer (score 1):

I think your API endpoints are protected by AWS_IAM authorization method. you can confirm it from the `Method Execution` section of your API endpoint.

If you are using AWS_IAM method, the api end points excepts a signature to be generated using your aws credentials and pass it in the request under the `Authorization` header.

You can use postman app to test the endpoint, follow these steps

1. create a new request with the correct http method and the url
2. under Authroization tab, select `AWS Signature`
3. Enter the values for `AccessKey`, `Secret Key`
4. under the `Advanced` section, enter your `region` and `Session Token`

Postman application is very handy to test rest api endpoints. it's even handy to test the api gateway endpoints protected by AWS_IAM authorization method. The postman app generates the signatures required using your AWS credentials and include the generated signature part of http headers of the request.

Note: Also make sure your identity pool's `Authenticated role` has permission to invoke the api endpoint.

Reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html

you can download postman application if you dont have - https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/

Comment: I know how to call an API using postman.  That is not the problem. The problem is configuring API Gateway with a Cognito User Pool.

Comment: thanks for explaining that clearly. Since you are getting AWS Credentials, your API gateway api method should use `AWS_IAM` authroization method. can you confirm that. you can check the current authorization method under the "method execution" section of your api endpoint.

Comment: How can I use the AWS signature on a javascript  frontend (e.g. using `fetch` function)?